# How to access Viewholder from Fragment activity in landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I currently have an Adapter class which displays the list of children names and beside the names, it displays the time they arrived to the school. 
Problem is when I rotate to landscape, the time values are lost.

The Adapter class is like -

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.children_item, parent, false);
        // Cache the views using the view holder pattern
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.childname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_name);
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_time);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

     @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        Child child = children.createStopFromCursor(cursor);

                    viewHolder.time.setText(strText);
                    viewHolder.time.setTextColor(0xff000000);
                    viewHolder.time.setTextSize(17);
                    viewHolder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.time.setBackgroundColor(nColor);
                    viewHolder.time.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
                    view.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

I delare this is Manifest under MainActivity Tag as -

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

In MyFragment Activity, I have -

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        //How do I access viewHolder or TextView "time" here
        }
    }
    }
```

How to access the viewHolder or TextView "time" to update values in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your `onCreate` of your Fragment:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

However, this should not be necessary since you specified your `configChanges` option to not re-create the activity, so something else is going wrong here.

Comment: Since I added configChanges, the problem now is it is adding portrait layout to landscape as well but the time values are not lost. I have a different layout for landscape which is not being showed due to configChanges=screenSize. How do I overcome this?

Comment: OK, if you have different layouts for portrait and landscape, you cannot use configChanges at all. However, by using setRetainInstance your fragment will be preserved with it's data when orientation changes.

Comment: I tried with setRetainInstance(true) but still no developments